# Its possible to record audio in my application while another application is playing audio?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

In my application I want to record audio or music from other application like Quicktime .. or Itunes music .. etc.

I run background mode in my application and start recording and I can open any application without any problem and recording still working , suddenly when I play the music from Quicktime or Itunes music or any other audioplayers application  , my application stopped recording and background disabled .

So my question  , its possible to record from my application while other apps playing music or audio ??

If yes how ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555038/iphone-allow-other-app-to-play-audio-while-recording-audio-shazam